# Transfer data from desktop to android device

Tags: c#, android

I have started working on Android platform a few days ago. I want to transfer data from a desktop computer to a android device (ICONIA TAB). I am using C# in the desktop computer and want to transfer data using wireless network.

For instance, if I move the cursor in a C# form, it will pass the corresponding coordinate values to the tablet.

any link / sample code to solve the problem would be greatly appreciated

Comment: i don't have much idea about android platform and thats why I need some kind of link / sample program.